# How to write matrix and its source code using cnltx-example

Tags: matrices, verbatim

I want to get output of the matrix

```
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{9}{5} \\
-2 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
12 & 0 & \frac{11}{7} \\
\end{pmatrix}
```

along with the code displayed side by side using

```
\begin{example}[side-by-side]
\end{example}
```

with `cnltx-example` package. When I am going to compile (with `amsart` documentclass) this, it gives an error. How to fix this?

Here is my code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsxtra,amsopn}
\usepackage{cnltx-example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[side-by-side]
  Consider the following example.
  \[ (x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2\]
\end{example}

%The following gives an error at the time of compiling
\begin{example}[side-by-side]
  Consider the following matrix.
$\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{9}{5} \\
-2 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
12 & 0 & \frac{11}{7} \\
\end{pmatrix}$
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add a small example document? (See [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: @ leandriis: I have added the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, `cnltx-example` requires an indentation of the code by two spaces:

```latex
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cnltx-example}

\begin{document}

\begin{example}[side-by-side]
  Consider the following example.
  \[ (x + y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2\]
\end{example}

%The following gives an error at the time of compiling
\begin{example}[side-by-side]
  Consider the following matrix.
  $\begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{9}{5} \\
  -2 & \frac{2}{3} & -\frac{1}{4} \\
  12 & 0 & \frac{11}{7} \\
  \end{pmatrix}$
\end{example}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Why this does not run in `beamer`?

Comment: @user149418 Are you using the `fragile` option for the frame?

Comment: @ egreg: Yes. I have posted it here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503302/cnltx-example-package-is-not-working-with-beamer